# Keras GradCam implementation that can process batches of images instead of a single image at a time

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, matrix-multiplication

I'm following the GradCam example from the Keras documentation https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/ and want to modify it so that it can process a batch of images instead of only a single image at a time.

I was already able to accomplish this but had to use a call to `tf.map_fn` which I would like to get rid of in the hopes of a performance improvement.

My progress so far (whole code at [Google Coolab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ptoRzS3WpThhHokX4p2nv-e2I-Oaq9bq?usp=sharing)):

```py
#https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/
def make_gradcam_heatmap(grad_model, images, pred_index=None):
    images = tf.cast(images, tf.float32)

    # Then, we compute the gradient of the top predicted class for our input image
    # with respect to the activations of the last conv layer
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(images)
        last_conv_layer_output, preds = grad_model(images)
        if pred_index is None:
            pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
        class_channel = preds[:, pred_index]

    # This is the gradient of the output neuron (top predicted or chosen)
    # with regard to the output feature map of the last conv layer
    grads = tape.gradient(class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)
    assert grads is not None, "GradientTape returned gradients=None"

    # This is a vector where each entry is the mean intensity of the gradient
    # over a specific feature map channel
    pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=(1, 2))

    # We multiply each channel in the feature map array
    # by "how important this channel is" with regard to the top predicted class
    # then sum all the channels to obtain the heatmap class activation
    def single_image(index):
        return last_conv_layer_output[index] @ pooled_grads[index][tf.newaxis, ..., tf.newaxis]

    heatmaps = tf.map_fn(single_image, tf.range(tf.shape(grads)[0]), dtype=tf.float32)

    # normalize the whole batch to [0, 1]
    heatmaps -= tf.math.reduce_min(heatmaps, axis=(0,1,2,3))
    heatmaps /= tf.math.reduce_max(heatmaps, axis=(0,1,2,3))

    return heatmaps
```

---

Is there any way to rewrite this code in such a way that it doesn't use `tf.map_fn`?

```py
    def single_image(index):
        return last_conv_layer_output[index] @ pooled_grads[index][tf.newaxis, ..., tf.newaxis]

heatmaps = tf.map_fn(single_image, tf.range(tf.shape(grads)[0]), dtype=tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `matmul`,

```
heatmaps = tf.matmul(last_conv_layer_output, pooled_grads[:,tf.newaxis, :, tf.newaxis])
```

Comment: That... works o.O... but I don't understand why. Why does calling matmul on the whole thing work even though it consists of a list of matrix... I mean knowing this I can even write `heatmaps = last_conv_layer_output @ pooled_grads[:,tf.newaxis, :, tf.newaxis]`

Comment: The shapes of the arguments are (3, 10, 10, 2048) and (3, 2048) respectively. In `batched matmul`, the first shape value is batch, which should be same for both, and the other condition is the diagonal shapes should be same or one of them should be 1. So we change (3,2048) to (3, 1, 2048, 1), to satisfy the condition. And matmul gives - (3, 10, 10, 1) as output.

Comment: you can also use `tf.einsum('ijkl,il->ijk', last_conv_layer_output, pooled_grads)`

Comment: Yes I was experimenting with einsum but matmul looks much cleaner. Many Thanks.